# Open a WPF app with parameters in an XML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I want to open my app (WPF based) with a file which contains parameters written in XML format.

How can I do that?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lloyd said, in WPF instead of using the arguments in the project startup class as you would in ie WinForms you extract this from the commmand line args.
This can b done whenever so in your first window ie you could do something like this:

```
public Window1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  string[] param = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

  // Your parameter is in the second one since the first contains the executable path or something like that
  string xmlPath = param[1];

  // Open and edit your xmlPath 
  // ....
}
```

Then you can simply drag&drop the xml you want ontop of your WPF executable or invoke it on commandline:

```
YourExecutable.exe myXml.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

I want to ask; do I able to invoke it from this file? For example Live Meeting gives an *.rtd file that provides invoking the executable. File contains these lines:

<rtc> 
   <Param authTicket ="" />
   <Param customAiccSid ="" />
   <Param customExtra1 ="" />    
   <Param customExtra2 ="" />
<Param customExtra3 ="" />
<Param customSource ="" />
<Param isLobby = ""/>
<Param role = "present"/>
<Param meetingEndTime ="" />
<Param meetingID ="" />
<Param meetingPassword ="" />
<Param meetingStartTime ="" />
<Param meetingSubject ="" />
</rtc>

Comment: Could you please clarify that a bit, what do you wish to invoke, the executable (the wpf app)?

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the properties folder in the solution explorer of the wpf project you want to set the parameters for and go ahead and open up the Settings.settings file. Here you can put your parameters in a type-safe manner and after adding a first one you will be presented with an app.config file which contains the xml values of your parameters. This file is then automatically copied when you build your project into the binaries folder with the name .exe.config instead of app.config. Use this file to distribute and change your settings once the application is built.

Bear in mind that you need to have the settings in the project that is your executable, I'm not sure how it works when you have the dll's settings.

To use your settings in code just use:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.<name_of_setting>
```

And you'll get the value that's written in the file with the type that's chosen on the settings.settings page.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the file name as a Command Line Argument and handle Command Line parameters in the [Application.Startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) Event. Or simply load the file from a parameter defined in your configuration setting in the same Event.